# How to theoretically predict thermodynamic stability?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, amines

Let's say we have $\ce{CH3-NH2}$ undergoing Hoffman's exhaustive methylation with $\ce{CH3-Cl}$. In which case side reactions such as $\ce{CH3-NH2 + CH3-NH2 -> CH3NHCH3 + NH3}$ would also occur.

How do we theoretically determine the relative difference in thermodynamic stability between the products of the side reaction ($\ce{CH3NHCH3 + NH3}$) and the main reaction?

Comment: I imagine it wouldn't dominate because we take methyl iodide in excess.

Comment: Okay I'll make this question more specific

Comment: The side reaction products will be more stable but would be kinetically unfeasible(comparitively high activation energy)

Comment: What is your side product: dimethyl amine (as suggested by the hydrogen on nitrogen)? The bonds of the leftmost carbon don’t add up …

Comment: @jan yes, made a mistake while typing this question sorry